# Getting Segmentation fault for implementing ByteSize() in C++ for protobuffer

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am new in protocol buffer. So, I am trying to implement a small c++ code for protocol-buffer3.
In my protocol buffer, I have only one variable

```
int32 val = 1;
```

In C++ code, when I use `Bytesize()` function to know the total size, but this application receives `segmentation fault` all the time.

Codes are 
test.proto

```
syntax = "proto3"

message testmsg {
    int32 val = 1;
}

//cpp codes
main(){
    testmsg test1;
    memset(&test1, 0, sizeof(testmsg));
    test1.set_val(1);                   // works fine
    cout<<test1.val()<<endl;            //works fine. Display the result
    int size = test1.ByteSize();        //---> Segmentation faults here
    cout << "size = " <<size;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Without code, we can't answer

Comment: With the information provided my best guess is.... you have a bug in your code.

Comment: I add the code as per your comment. Thank you

Comment: `memset`?? I don't consider this C++ code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
memset function is creating this problem.
I removed the memset function. it works fine